# How prevent Pixel 2 from sleeping while dictating?

Tags: voice-recording, google-pixel-2

I just dictated a long email message, but several times during the dictation, my Pixel 2 went into sleep mode, so I had to unlock it to continue dictating. Is there a setting I have to modify to keep it from doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I saw a reviewer talking about that and i believe there is no fix in settings for that but I can recommend you an app called [caffeine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.syntaxa.caffeine) that keeps your phone awake for a set amount of time